# Why does PowerPoint select a different shape than the one I click?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

In PowerPoint 2013 why does a shape get selected when clicking cleary outside it's boundaries.

See this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

- both textboxes have outlines to show their boundaries
- I try to clicking the "Shape"-Textbox (right where the cursor is) to select that textbox

Instead the larger shape on top gets selected.

Annoying ways around that are:

1. Move the large shape to the back. Somehow it seems PowerPOint thinks it overlaps and is front?
2. Use the mouse to drag a selection around the "Shape" text box.

Ideas?

**Update:** Here is a [sample presentation](http://download.veodin.com/misc/SelectTextShape.pptx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the original answer in place because it might fit somebody else's situation.
In this case, the problem is that both text boxes have a reflection effect applied; the selectable area of the text box extends to include the reflection.  You can't see the reflection because it's set to 100% transparent.  Remove that and all will be well.

Notice that it's not really clicking Shape B that causes Shape A to be selected.  It's just that the invisible reflection applied to Shape A extends over Shape B.  Move them further apart vertically and you won't have the "selection crosstalk"

If the upper text box is set not to autofit, then the text frame can extend beyond the boundaries of the textbox/shape itself.  Click on the final "Tex" line then press the down arrow key a few times.  If the text cursor keeps moving downward, below the outline of the text box, that's the problem.  Either set the text box to autofit (Rightclick, Format Shape, Text Box, click "Resize shape to fit text") or once the text cursor no longer moves downward when you press down-arrow, start pressing backspace until you get back to the end of the visible text (aka delete all the extraneous line-endings)

Comment: Thanks, interesting point and I double checked that the text does not extend with empty line breaks. I also tried both settings "Do not Autofit" and "Resize shape to fit text" with no luck. I'll update the question to include the sample .pptx